# How do I find all the data containing an id from a list of ids in Spark?

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, apache-spark

Right now I have an inefficient approach:

```
ids = [...]
matched = []
    for id in ids:
        d = data.where(data.id == id)
        d = d.take(1)
        matched.append(d[0][3])
```

I'm wondering how I can do this faster?
The data contains 4 column, where the fourth one contains ids.

-UPDATE-

Perhaps like this?

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(data, "data")
s = ','.join(str(e) for e in ids)
q = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id IN (" + s + ")")
sqlContext.sql(q).collect()
```

This takes 5 min instead of 40 min at the approach above.

Comment: So, ids is a list of Rows? Why is it not a RDD or data frame?

Comment: It's a dataframe I believe, but I'm sure because I just started using Spark. What do you think is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you are collecting all of the data on the driver node, and processing it in python. You aren't getting the benefits of using Spark because the approach isn't distributed.

The second approach uses spark SQL and is distributed. You could also use RDD apis as below. The RDD APIs are more flexible, but typically a bit slower. If you can use the dataframe APIs (or SQL ones as above), stick with those.

```
ids = [...]
data.rdd.filter(lambda x: x.id in ids).collect()
```

Comment: Thank you. 4 min and 35 seconds :)